# Tagging a product whose components are placed in different svn repositories

Tags: svn, version

I am managing a set of software projects, namely, X, Y and Z. There is a set of dependencies among them, i.e. X --> Y --> Z. It means that project X depends on the interfaces of Project Y and Y is dependent to Z interfaces.

Unfortunately, X, Y and Z are kept on separate svn repositories. Now the question is how can I take a snapshot (create a tag) of a stable version of my product, including specific versions of X, Y and Z? Any solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `externals` feature in SVN.  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.externals.html

Comment: Externals are a way to created a working folder from different repositories, not getting tags !!!!

Comment: You can specify a tag as an external, or you can specify a given revision as an external.  Either should suit your purpose.  A tag is a folder as far as svn is concerned.

Comment: You can use it to map to a particular version of a remote repo.  Read the link.

Comment: @tripleee: The link you posted is from an extremely old version of the Subversion book.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up; I updated the link.  I wish Google would check this for me (-:

Comment: From the doc above: "... using explicit revision numbers also means that as you backdate your working copy to a previous revision, your externals definitions will also revert to the way they looked in that previous revision, which in turn means that the external working copies will be updated to match the way they looked back when your repository was at that previous revision". Tags should work as expected and pull the corresponding revisions out of the separate repositories.

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been suggested you can use [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.externals.html) to record the relationships among different variants of your projects. The idea is to define a root project so that by checking out either the trunk, a branch or a tag of this project you'll check out the correct variant of each of the other projects. So, assuming you have:

```
svn://repo1/X
svn://repo2/Y
svn://repo3/Z
```

You should create a root project like

```
svn://repo4/root
```

where

```
svn://repo4/root/trunk
```

will have externals defined as

```
X svn://repo1/X/trunk
Y svn://repo2/Y/trunk
Z svn://repo3/Z/trunk
```

and

```
svn://repo4/root/tags/TAG
```

will have externals defined as

```
X svn://repo1/X/tags/TAG
Y svn://repo2/Y/tags/TAG
Z svn://repo3/Z/tags/TAG
```

You can create the initial externals definition with the [svn propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html) command; when you want to create a new tag you tag all your projects separately as usual, including root. Then you check out the new root tag with the *--ignore-externals* option and set your externals again with the corresponding tag URL's.

Answer (score 1):

[svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.externals.html) does the job for you as already mentioned ... . Check [this blog post](http://thinkinging.com/2008/10/21/set-the-revision-of-your-svnexternals-or-else/) for a step by step description. The first blog comment improves the workflow using a "release branch".

Comment: +1 The article covers the proper usage of the fixed revision numbers in the externals.